# Polarizations in algebraic and symplectic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, abelian-varieties, quantization

In context of Abelian varieties there are a couple of equivalent ways to
introduce the *polarization* of a algebraic variety. One way is to
choose a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ which satisfies certain identities.

Seemingly the historical motivation for the name "*polarization*" in theory of algebraic varieties
is that the Chern class of this line bundle
$\mathcal{L}$ has similar properties like the Chern class of Kähler form
in complex analytic geometry. Indeed the name "*polarization*" occurs also
in symplectic geometry and a [*Kähler polarization*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K%C3%A4hler+polarization) of a symplectic manifold
by definition a polarization by a compatible Kähler manifold structure. Where
the last *polarization* is in symplectic sense:

Let $(X, \omega)$  be a symplectic manifold. A polarization [polarization in symplectic sense](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polarization) of
$(X, \omega)$ is a choice of involutive Lagrangian subbundle
$\mathcal{P} \subset T_{\mathbb{C}} X$ of of the complexified
tangent bundle of $X$.

Questions:

1. Does the name *polarization* for Abelian varieties arise and is just "transfered"
   from the terminology for symplectic manifolds or are the "polarizations"
   in algebraic geometry and symplectic geometry not really related to each
   other?
2. Let us focus on *polarizations* in theory of symplectic manifolds. The choice if a polarization plays eg an important role in geometric quantizations.
   Does the name polarization in symplectic geometry have some geometrical &
   intuitive meaning. I understand the definition but I would like to know
   what was the motivation behind the name polarization there.

Naively one associates the polarization with certain physical phenomena
from optics. Does the motivation behind the choice of the name polarization in
symplectic geometry have a physical origin?

adds: I had a look [at the thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177208/why-polarization-of-abelian-varieties) linked by Tabes Bridges but the
discussion there not provides a satisfying answer of
my question at all except that this name firstly was used to study abelian varieties and later it was token by symplectic/differential geometers, that is it have been established in reverse order to that what I conjectured above as Tabes Bridges remarked in his comment. According to an answer I found there the term "polarization" was coined by Andre Weil but there is no explanation why he choosed this name. I cannot imagine that he choosed this name ad hoc "randomly" without
having any association with something in mind. I'm very curious if there is something "more" behind his choice of this term.

Comment: The top answer to this question addresses the historical origins of the notion of a polarization of an Abelian variety, which is apparently due to Weil: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177208/why-polarization-of-abelian-varieties So to answer question 1, I believe the story is the reverse of what you conjectured: as far as I know, the notion of a polarized abelian variety predates the establishment of symplectic geometry as a genuine field of study....

Comment: ...However, given that a polarization is almost enough to determine a canonical Kähler form, one would hope that if there is any justice in the world then the two concepts coincide. (I say "almost" because you may need to take a tensor power of the line bundle to get an embedding, and then there is no canonical choice of power; once you have an embedding, pull back the Fubini-Study form from projective space; and I don't know if it's easy to describe the change in the Kähler structure under a Veronese re-embedding)

Comment: Existence of Polarisation is the main problem in Symplectic Geometry. It has important application in quantization of physical systems.

Comment: @TabesBridges: so as far as I understood the answer of the linked question it will stay Weil's sectret at all why he called them "polarizations" and there is most probably no direct analogy from other scientific fields motivating to justify  the choice of this name?

Comment: @HassanJolany: Yes, but the main concern of my question is **why** the "polarization" is called "polarization" in symplectic geometry & study of abelian varieties. So it is more focused on the origin of name itself.

Comment: @IsaktheXI I wouldn't say it's a secret. The answer says that he chose the name by analogy with orientation, presumably because it does something like tell us which line bundles are positive.

Comment: @TabesBridges This is roughly correct, but there is an infinite dimensional family of K\"ahler metrics in a fixed K\"ahler class, and the set of "Fubini-Study" metrics you describe is dense. So an ample line bundle is really very far from enough to produce a canonical K\"ahler metric!

Comment: @RuadhaíDervan Can you elaborate? Are you saying that a *very* ample line bundle is not enough, or just an ample? The latter I can absolutely believe, but once we have a very ample bundle we have a fixed embedding into projective space with its fixed Fubini Study metric which seems like it should be enough. Or are you referring to the need to normalize $\omega_{FS}$?

Comment: You get a Fubini-Study metric once you fix an embedding in projective space; this requires not only an ample line bundle but a basis of global sections. There is no canonical way of choosing a basis, so no canonical Fubini-Study metric!